# Proper OOP PHP Class structure and DB interaction

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, pdo

I am fairly new to OOP and PHP. I worked my way through Kevin Yank's book and wanted to keep advancing to some OOP concepts. But I am a bit lost and I need help.

I am trying to generate a list of vendors from the DB using a Vendor Class.
Fields such as city and country use an ID (relational DB using a city and country table), so I will also need to be able to grab the name values for those before I publish the complete list in my html output file.

I can do all this procedurally, but struggling to find the right structure when moving to OOP.

I followed Kevin's instructions and created a db.inc.php file for my PDO db connection:

```
<?php 

//db connection using PDO class object

try {

    //create new PDO class object
    $pdo = new   
    PDO('mysql:host=122.2.2.2;port=3307;dbname=mydbname','dbuser','password');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');

}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    //if unable to connect, tell us why
    $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server 2.'.$e->getMessage();
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}
```

I created a Vendor Class. This class will hold all the methods to manipulate vendors: getVendors(), getVendor($id), deleteVendor($id), updateVendor($id), etc.

```
<?php


class Vendor {

    protected $name;
    protected $address;
    protected $city;
    protected $state;
    protected $postal;
    protected $country;
    protected $tel;
    protected $email;
    protected $web;


    public function __construct(){

        //typically first function to appear in a class
        // Constructor using MagicMethod
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->city = $city;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->postal = $postal;
        $this->country = $country;
        $this->tel= $tel;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->web = $web;

    }

    public  function getVendors($pdo){

        //get all vendor data from db
        try
        {
            //prepares a statement for execution and returns a statement object
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM vendor ORDER BY name");
            $query->execute();

            $vendors = array();

            foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $row){

            //create array of member objects
            $vendors[] = new Vendor($row);
        }

        //return member objects
        //not sure this is the right thing to do here
        return $vendors;

        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
             //handle any errors
             $output = 'Error fetching vendors: ' . $e->getMessage();
             include 'output.html.php';
             exit();

        }//end try catch
    }//end function


    //setters

    public function setName( $name ){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setAddress( $address ){
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    public function setCity( $city ){
        $this->city = $city;
    }

    public function setState( $state ){
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    public function setPostal( $postal ){
        $this->postal = $postal;
    }

    public function setCountry( $country ){
        $this->country = $country;
    }

    public function setTel( $tel ){
        $this->tel = $tel;
    }

    public function setEmail( $email ){
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function setWeb( $web ){
        $this->web = $web;
    }


    //getters

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getAddress(){
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function getCity(){
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function getState(){
        return $this->state;
    }

    public function getPostal(){
        return $this->postal;
    }

    public function getCountry(){
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function getTel(){
        return $this->tel;
    }

    public function getEmail(){
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getWeb(){
        return $this->web;
    }

}
```

I have an index.php file that is calling the list of vendors

```
<?php 

//get all vendors

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/db.inc.php'; 
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/includes/Vendor.Class.php'; 

//instantiate class
$vendor = new Vendor();

//calling my function to get a list of all vendors
//not sure if passing in $pdo object is a good idea/practice

$vendors = $vendor->getVendors($pdo);

//test print out vendors
echo $vendors;
print_r($vendors);

//output to template
include 'output.html.php';
```

The idea is to then use a template/output html file to output data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>

    <?php foreach ($vendors as $vendor){

        //if my city is an id value, at what point do I call the City Class to look up   
        that city name? I should not be calling DB from my view. And is it OK to have  
        html code in my controller?

        $name = $vendor->getName();
        $address2 = $vendor->getAddress2();
        $city = $vendor->getCity();
        $zip = $vendor->getZip();
        $web = $vendor->getWeb();
        $phone = $vendor->getTel();


    ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

My questions:

1. In my vendor class I am creating an array of Vendor Objects - is this the correct OOP way of returning my rows of Vendors from DB?
2. If my country and city are IDs, and each has their own class, when and where is the appropriate time to call those classes and use getCity($id) and getCountry($id) to get name values instead of ids, and work them into my foreach statement?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your Vendor object should only be a container for data and *not* tightly couple it to a specific DBMS.

Comment: You're conflating two subjects--OOP design and patterns for database abstraction. I'm sorry if that's just more confusing, but it will help you in your searching if you don't consider those parts of the same whole, because they aren't.

Comment: Sure, you could abstract it out more and make a VendorCollection class or something to handle groups of Vendors differently, but it really depends on what you're doing. Do you have a lot of Vendors?  Is it a good UI concept to display them all on the screen at the same time?  Is it a good idea to load them all into memory at once?  Do you have a way of building  and returning a single vendor? You really shouldn't be worrying about "returning rows from a DB", you should be worried more about creating an API to instantiate and manipulate objects, the DB part of it will come naturally from that

Comment: Good luck, nowadays PHP actually has quite decent support for OOP, tho, most of the API is procedural, like php `array` wich is not an object, so I will always think that PHP is a OOP mess that doesnt help its own learning, really dislike it since i moved on from php, but ugh, programmers... what you use the most is what ull get to love :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you should make separate classes to get the city name and country name just create a view in your database selecting the details of the vendor replacing ids with names and select * from it...
and just to keep things simple put all the properties into an array is a better option
just save the returned array from the sql into the array...